# Footer appears automatically but is not an add-in

Tags: microsoft-excel

Recently my company released an update that started putting a footer on all our MS Office docs, including Excel. I've disabled all Excel and COM Add-ins but it still appears automatically. In Page Setup > Header/Footer the new auto-text appears for new and existing documents. I'm stumped as to how it gets there. The company is very large so tracing the source of the update is not easy. Ideally I'd like to remove or at least reformat it. I can force it in VBA but would like to know if there's a more user-friendly answer.

Comment: It might be that a VBA macro was added by the update.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. No new code was added.

Comment: Another: Maybe `Normal.dotm` was replaced.

Comment: If it is a macro pushed out by the company, it may be a 'personal.xlsb' one... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790